# How to use $unset and $set in combination in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have record like this :

```
{
    "Date" : ISODate("2013-06-28T18:30:00Z"),
    "Details" : {
            "Amount1" : -200,
            "Amount2" : 2800,
            "Amount3" : -100
    },
    'NID' : 'T123RT',
    'PID' : 'P123RT',
    "SettAmount" : 2500,
    "SettStatus" : "completed",
    "Status" : "completed",
    "StoreID" : "51ea54279d867b040b000008",
    "_id" : ObjectId("51ea54279d867b040b000013")
}
```

I am trying to update the document like :

```
db.settlements.update({
    'StoreID' : "51ea54279d867b040b000008",
    'Date' : ISODate("2013-06-28T18:30:00Z")
}, {
    $unset : {
        'NID' : "",
        'PID' : ""
    }
    }, {
    $set : {
        'SettStatus' : 'start',
        'Status' : 'pending'
    }
});
```

But, only unset operation is successful. what is the error in above query........?

Comment: too many braces? The $set is moved out of the second parameter to `update` into its own third (which does something else or nothing).

Answer (score 61):

you have too many braces, 
here's correct command:

```
db.settlements.update(
    {
        'StoreID': "51ea54279d867b040b000008",
        'Date': ISODate("2013-06-28T18:30:00Z")
    }, 
    {
        $unset: {
            'NID' : "",
            'PID' : ""
        }, 
        $set: {
            'SettStatus': 'start',
            'Status': 'pending'
        }
    }
);
```

in your command, you're using $set as `<options>` in update command, not as part of `<update>`

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#crud-update-update

Comment: What will mongodb execute first? `$set` or `$unset`?
What if same fields are being updated in both operations?

Comment: @Anmol Mongodb will execute the $set and $unset at the same time, and if same fields are being updated in both operations, mongodb will throw an error like - `Updating the path 'field_name' would create a conflict at 'field_name'`