# How to set and unset simultaneously in MongoDB from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unset

I have the following code to set data :

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoConnectionUrl, function (err, db) {
          if (err) {
              console.log("error");
          } else {                  
              var collection = db.collection(collectionName);
              collection.updateOne(query, {
                  "$set": data
              }, function (err) {
                  if (err) {
                      console.log("eror");                          
                  } else {
                    console.log("success.........");                         
                  }
                  db.close();
              });
          }
      });
```

How can I set data and unset some fields simultaneously?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760741/how-to-use-unset-and-set-in-combination-in-mongodb please check this thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator in the same [update operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/):

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoConnectionUrl, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("error");
  } else {
    var collection = db.collection(collectionName);
    collection.updateOne(query, {
      "$set"  : data,
      "$unset": data,
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("eror");
      } else {
        console.log("success.........");
      }
      db.close();
    });
  }
});
```