# How to update the row and unset some field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a user collection which has.

- firstName.
- lastName.
- deactivatedAt.
- deactivatedBy.
- Status (0: deactive, 1: active).

When the user is active then **deactivatedAt and deactivatedBy**  should be removed from the collection.

when the user is de-active then **deactivatedAt and deactivatedBy** should be available in the collection.

I do the following action.

1-> when I deactive the user, I set **deactivatedAt and deactivatedBy**.

2-> When I active the user then the  **deactivatedAt and deactivatedBy** should be removed from the collection.

My action.

```
module.exports.deactive = function(req, res) {
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  let params = {
    status: 0,
    deactivatedAt: new Date(),
    deactivatedBy: {
      userId: req.payload._id,
      firstName: req.payload.firstName,
      lastName: req.payload.lastName
    }
  };
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, params, {new: true})
    .then(result => {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 200, {message: 'User successfully deactivated'});
    })
    .catch(err => {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 500, {message: 'Error occurred'});
    })
};

module.exports.active = function(req, res) {
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  let params = {
    status: 1
  };


  //------------ in here in need to remove the deactivatedAt and deactivated By


  User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, params)
    .then(result => {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 200, {message: 'User successfully activated'});
    })
    .catch(err => {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 500, {message: 'Error occurred'});
    })
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use $unset of mongo for this case, Please check more info from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use $unset in update() for deleting fields from collection

```
let params = { 
     $unset : {
          deactivatedAt : 1,
          deactivatedBy : 1
     }
};
User.update({_id : user_id}, params)
.then(result => {
    sendJsonResponse(res, 200, {message: 'User successfully activated'});
})
.catch(err => {
    sendJsonResponse(res, 500, {message: 'Error occurred'});
});
```

And when user is not active, you can again set values using **$set**

```
let params = { 
     $set : {
          deactivatedAt : <value>,
          deactivatedBy : <value>
     }
};
User.update({_id : user_id}, params)
.then(result => {
    sendJsonResponse(res, 200, {message: 'User successfully deactivated'});
})
.catch(err => {
    sendJsonResponse(res, 500, {message: 'Error occurred'});
});
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks.

Comment: At the same time, how to set ?

Comment: You can use $set and update() to set values again. I have made changes in my answer. Or The code you have written to deactivate is working right?

Comment: It is not possible to use $set and $unset at the same time?

Comment: It is possible to use $set and $unset at the same time. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760741/how-to-use-unset-and-set-in-combination-in-mongodb